# fprintf crashes my program when it meets a \n

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to make a report in a .txt file, but when my `fprintf` meets a `\n` it crashes. This is my code concerning the opening of the file and crashing:

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("estructuras.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "");
printf("3"); //This is the last thing I see.
fprintf(f, "TEXT TO INPUT\n")
fclose(f);
```

Comment: You fail to check the value of `f`, for example `if(f == NULL) { exit(1); }`

Comment: That's not a complete program. Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: works for me on windows even when the file cannot be created. Have you tried with a debugger

Comment: Please do not post "something like your code". This is **not** your actual code (it would not compile). Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you didn't check whether the file opened. If it failed, it will return NULL and that will do bad things to `fprintf`.

Your first `fprintf(f, "");` is a no-op. Printing an empty string does nothing, so that "works" (though I doubt that's guaranteed). `printf("3");` does to stdout and is unaffected by the failed `fopen`. `fprintf(f, "TEXT TO INPUT\n")` finally tries to print to NULL and pukes.

All system calls have to be checked. They all have different return values on error. `fopen` returns NULL and the error lies in `errno`. There's many ways to do `fopen` error handling, here's one that I like which gives the user information to debug the problem.

```
#include <string.h>    // for strerror()
#include <errno.h>     // for errno
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    // Put the filename in a variable so it can be used in the
    // error message without needing to be copied.
    char file[] = "estructuras.txt";

    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "w");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        // Display the filename, what you were doing with it, and why it wouldn't open.
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s' for writing: %s\n", file, strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

`strerror(errno)` turns the numeric `errno` error code into a human readable string. There are quotes around the filename in case extra whitespace snuck in.

So you'll get an error like `Could not open 'estructuras.txt': No such file or directory`.

Comment: is that "printing to NULL" behaviour guaranteed? because on windows the program doesn't crash. I found that link: http://computer-programming-forum.com/47-c-language/3b3b0abba003f0d6.htm. Sounds undefined behaviour / implementation defined.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre [MSVC man page for `fprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh07fe2.aspx) says *"If `stream` or `format` is `NULL`, these functions invoke the invalid parameter handler, as described in [Parameter Validation]. If execution is allowed to continue, the functions return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINVAL`."*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm going to guess it's Undefined Behavior. A quick skim of C99's stdio.h and fprintf specs doesn't say anything about null pointers. Closest I see is *The fprintf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred* so it could return a negative avlue, but clang chooses to segfault. Note: this answer is just pulling apart the observed behavior.

Comment: @DavidBowling that does seem to apply to a `NULL` *argument* pointer, for example `fprintf(f, "%s", NULL);` kindly sends `"(null)"` to the (valid) file. However `fputs(NULL, f);` crashes.

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe that's also UB. I don't see any reference to what `%s` is supposed to do with a null pointer in C99.

Comment: @Schwern I was querying the angle from DavidBowling which did not seem to be about a `NULL` file pointer, but `NULL` data. It is quite unreasonable to suppose that a `NULL` file pointer will be well handled. Aside: I replicated what Jean-François Fabre said: the MSVC test program did not error: but UB does not necessarily fail.

Comment: My rule of thumb is this: don't push the edge cases of a language if you don't have to; especially C which tends to watch quietly as you step over the edge. Then we don't have to remember how many pointers can dance on the head of a pin. :)